# Getting Value From Input text from input type button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

so i have been trying to reach the value from a input text and set it in on a string, i've tried 4 different ways and for some reason I get `String = ""` or `String` Is Nothing

Code VB Behind

```
Public Sub subscriber(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim check_Mail As String = subs_text.Value()
    If check_Mail = Nothing Then
        alertJava("Working Empty")
    Else
        alertJava(check_Mail.ToString())
    End If
End Sub
```

tried as well

```
Dim checkmail as string = Page.Request.Form("subs_text")
Dim checkmail as string = Request("subs_text")
Dim checkmail as string = Request(subs_text.value())
```

HTML Code I Have

```
<div class="input-group"> ------
  <input id="subs_text" runat="server" name="subs_text" type="text" class="form-control">
    <placeholder="Email Adress"> / -----
    <span class="input-group-btn"> ----
      <input type="button" runat="server" onserverclick="subscriber" class="btn btn-primary" value="JoinUS"> ----
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any code that could be resetting page values on post back?

Comment: no sir nothing resetting values on post back

Comment: do you have a form somewhere around your inputs?

Comment: yes i actually have [HTML] <form  id="subs_form"> [/HTML] I dont have runat=server because i already have another form in same page with runat=server and asp:Button .....

Comment: are you sure which form is submitted?

Comment: yes, i actually jut tried adding subs_text.Attributes.add(CheckMail, subs_text.value()) and its keeping the value of CheckMail which i did now is Public CheckMail as String = "test" but not changing for the actual value of the text field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is actually the value since the form is not in a Runat=server the postback value comes back in the uniqueID instead of the actual value so

Dim Check_Main as String = Request.Form(TEXTFIELD_ID.UniqueID)

hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the value="" attribute. Therefore, its always empty

Comment: the value is set when you type on the actual textfield .. even if i set Value="testing" when i click it comes as empty

Comment: Ok, can you add a test page to your project and add only this html and code behind code just to see whether its working. If it's working then you'll have to look into the other parts of the code/ html

Comment: i took EnableEventValidation="False"  off and im getting Invalid postback or callback argument.

Comment: Why did you do that? And, where did you set this value? In your page's @Page directive or in your web.config? FYI- If you set EnableEventValidation="False" it's insecure.

Comment: What's your input value? Did you try with a new (test) page?

Comment: removed the enableeventvalidation="false" i know is insecure, jsut wanted to try, the value is in the html tag, value="test" and it comes back as "test" with no problem the problem is when i type "This is a 2nd Test" the value still is "test" when postback

Comment: Hmmm, odd. I believe you are testing in a new page and you only have html within the <div class="input-group"> tag and subscriber method in code behind, right?

Comment: want me to send you the test project complete so you can try it yourself to see if you can help please

Comment: Ok send it and I'll have a look

Comment: sorry Sam for the delay, got it resolved ill post the solution right now

Comment: tried to post it but cant for 24 hrs or somethn like that well Is actually the value since the form is not in a Runat=server the postback value comes back in the uniqueID instead of the actual value so

Dim Check_Main as String = Request.Form(TEXTFIELD_ID.UniqueID)

thanks everyone for the responses